# Excel if then statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a long list of points on a spreadsheet. I need a cell to say the point (m1-1), (m1-2) and so on. And I don't need it to say m 1 minus 1. I need it m1 dash 1. That is the point type.  I want it to where I can just type the number 1 or 2 or 3 and m1-1, m1-2, m1-3 will appear in that cell. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: how can this question be on hold when the user has already stated the given answer worked (even though they have yet to mark it)?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this by creating a custom format for the cell(s).

The custom format is: `"m1-"?`
When you enter a number in the cell (ie 2, 3, 7) it formats it as `m1-*n*`
See the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  It's doing exactly what we needed it to now!

Comment: @DChilcote - since the problem is solved, please mark the question as answered by clicking the check mark on the top left of the answer.